# Loading indicator when button is clicked (reactjs and ant design)

Tags: reactjs

I made a button that changes its label from 'extract' to 'extracted' when clicked then it becomes disabled. What I want to do now is for it to have a loading indicator when clicked and stop when the button is disabled.

I tried

### document.getElementById(inputID).setAttribute("loading", "true");

when button is clicked but found out that it doesn't work on buttons. I am also trying right now to use setState with my

### document.getElementById("btnTesting").innerHTML = "EXTRACTED";

```
class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
    }
  onClickBtn = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true});
    document.getElementById("btnTesting").innerHTML = "EXTRACTED";
    document.getElementById("btnTesting").setAttribute("disabled","true");
  }
    render() {
       return (
          <Button id="btnTesting" onClick={this.onClickBtn} loading={this.state.loading}>EXTRACT</Button>
       )
    }
  }
```

I expect to have a loading indicator when clicked then stop when button is disabled. But the screen turns blank. I look in the console and saw this error

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

The above error occurred in the  component:
blah .
blah .

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

Comment: First things first. Why don't you handle the button text and disabled attribute within the state?

Comment: When I used state, my other buttons get changed too. So I tried using innerHTML

Comment: @Alex.Reid. You would have to use separate state value for all the buttons to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using React, you don't need to use the `innerHTML` or `setAttribute` to change button text or disabled state.

You can use state varibles `buttonText`, initialised to "Extract" and `isDisabled`, initialised to false, and you can change the state after the button is done executing.

```
class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      buttonText: "EXTRACT",
      isDisabled: false
    };
  }
  onClickBtn = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        buttonText: "EXTRACTED",
        isDisabled: true,
        loading: false
      });
    }, 2000);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        id="btnTesting"
        onClick={this.onClickBtn}
        loading={this.state.loading}
        disabled={this.state.isDisabled}
      >
        {this.state.buttonText}
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

I've added a setTimeout of 2000ms so you can see the loading indicator.

Find the demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-l1d4r

Comment: what if I have multiple buttons? How can I use my button ID? We actually have a dynamic ID from API. So our ID looks something like this `id={`extractButton-${value.sectionID}${value.specimenID}${value.requestID}`}`

Comment: Then your state can have objects for each button ID with the button text and loading state and disabled state. I've updated my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-l1d4r) with multiple buttons

Comment: Yess. Exactly what I needed. I'll also try using dynamic object names. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if  below code solves your issue ? I Added timer to demonstrate time affect so that loading becomes evident.

With ReactJS, you don't have to use setAttribute or innerHTML as ReactJS uses virtualDOM. Even if you use them, It can get DOM in inconsistent state.  As per standard React practice you should handle your requirements (i.e changing DOM) with state variables

```
class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        loading: {"btn1": false},
        disabled: false,
        buttonText: 'Extract'
      }
    onClickBtn = (btnStr) => {
      let loadingCopy = Object.assign({},this.state.loading)
      loadingCopy[btnStr] = true
      this.setState({loading: loadingCopy})
      setInterval(() => {
        loadingCopy[btnStr] = false
        this.setState({ loading: loadingCopy, buttonText: 'Extracted', disabled: true });
        }, 3000);
    }
    render() {
       return (
          <ButtononClick={() =>this.onClickBtn("btn1")} loading={this.state.loading["btn1"]} disabled={this.state.disabled}>{this.state.buttonText}</Button>
         )
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I tried this weeks before. But what happens is if I have multiple buttons, they all load and change label at the same time. But this is what I needed . I just don't know what I should do if I have multiple buttons. PS: I'm a beginner in Reactjs.

Comment: `<Button id="btn1" onClick={this.onClickBtn} loading={this.state.loading} disabled={this.state.disabled}>{this.state.buttonText}</Button>
          <Button id="btn2" onClick={this.onClickBtn} loading={this.state.loading} disabled={this.state.disabled}>{this.state.buttonText}</Button>`

Comment: In that case each button should use different state variable for loading and button text.  This could messy, so you can use arrays to represent each loading text.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have updated my answer (check how state loading is being updated now) to give you an idea. You will have to do same for other 2 states too.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Button } from 'antd';
import React from "react";

class SubmitButton extends React.Component {
state = {
    loadings: [],
};

enterLoading = index => {
    this.setState(({loadings}) => {
        const newLoadings = [...loadings];
        newLoadings[index] = true;

        return {
            loadings: newLoadings,
        };
    });
};

render() {
    const {loadings} = this.state;
    return (
        <>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" loading={loadings[0]} onClick={() => this.enterLoading(0)}>
                Submit
            </Button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-framework-w5lmc?file=/src/App.js