# Loading indicator after clicking of button with dynamic id name

Tags: reactjs, antd

[Loading indicator when button is clicked (reactjs and ant design)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56950115/loading-indicator-when-button-is-clicked-reactjs-and-ant-design)

This is my original question but after a lot of trial and error, I still haven't figured it out. It turns out I didn't explain it clearly because I didn't understand it at first.

So this is the scenario:

1. I have multiple buttons with dynamic id. The number of buttons is not specific per item. My id looks like this

   `<Button id={${value.sectionID}${value.specimenID}${value.requestID}}>
   (Extract or Extracted)
   </Button>`
2. "loading" is based on state. And I was thinking if it's wise to put "Extract" and "Extracted" in the state as well

When I click a specific button with the initial label "EXTRACT", it must have a loading indicator for 2sec, change the label to "EXTRACTED" and then disable the button.

What I've done in a separate file for testing is that I made buttons with id "btnTesting1" and "btnTesting2". In my first post about this question, someone suggested that I should use an object inside the state.

```
this.state = {
      btnTesting1: {
          loading: false,
          buttonText: "EXTRACT",
          isDisabled: false
        },
        btnTesting2: {
          loading: false,
          buttonText: "EXTRACT",
          isDisabled: false
        }
}
```

this is working just fine but I have no idea what to do if my id is dynamic.

Code from original file

```
    <Button 
        id={`extract-${value.sectionID}${value.specimenID}${value.requestID}`}
        onClick={this.onChange} 
        disabled={value.phlebo_sampleSpecimenID}
        >
        {value.phlebo_sampleSpecimenID ? 'EXTRACTED' : 'EXTRACT'} 
    </Button>
```

Code from my testing file ( And this is the approach I want to do )

```
onClickBtn = evt => {
      const buttonId = evt.target.id;
        this.setState({
          [buttonId]: {
            loading: true
          }
        });
       etTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({
            [buttonId]: {
              buttonText: "EXTRACTED",
              isDisabled: true,
              loading: false
            }
          });
        }, 2000);
        console.log(buttonId);
};


 <Button 
          id="btnTesting1" 
          onClick={this.onClickBtn}
          loading={this.state.btnTesting1.loading}
          disabled={this.state.btnTesting1.isDisabled}
          >
            {this.state.btnTesting1.buttonText}
 </Button>
 <Button 
          id="btnTesting2" 
          onClick={this.onClickBtn}
          loading={this.state.btnTesting2.loading}
          disabled={this.state.btnTesting2.isDisabled}
          >
            {this.state.btnTesting2.buttonText}
 </Button>
```

SOOO, TO SUM IT ALL UP. HOW CAN I MAKE THE BUTTONS LOAD AND CHANGE LABELS SEPARATELY USING STATE AND WITH DYNAMIC IDs AND THEN DISABLE.

I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of weeks now. And I'm still a beginner in Reactjs. Any ideas and suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So... what is not working? What is the expected result? Your question still not clear (at least for me), and try to provide an **example** of the desired behavior. If you can providing a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a sandbox will be great (like https://codesandbox.io/s/new)

Comment: Maybe you can create your custom button component in which you can deal click event etc. without caring about ids.